# Baseband uses full bandwidth of the entire link or portion of the bandwidth?

Tags: signal, ethernet, baudrate, bit-rate

We know that modern Ethernet is full-duplex. At the same time we can send Or receive the signal. Suppose I consider one Lan where multiple hosts are connected by different ports of switch.

Let's take host A host connected switch port N via baseband link. Consider A starts sending signal to switch and at the same time switch  also starts sending signal to A.

My question is both host A and switch uses entire bandwidth of that baseband link at the same time or uses portion of the bandwidth of this baseband  link?

[image]

Comment: @brhans "the entire link"-- mean respective link between two devices, here MN.

Comment: @brhans all pairs are ethernet cable. If I choose fast Ethernet (100 mbps) .

Comment: Nevermind. I give up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Ethernet packet uses the full bandwidth of an Ethernet cable. You can only send one packet at a time, and receive one packet at a time.

Comment: when two packets meet at point X ,say in between the link MN then also at that point X also uses full bandwidth ?