# How Ethernet uses full bandwidth of the link if one host is sending more than one frame for different hosts?

Tags: signal, ethernet, baudrate, bit-rate

I followed from this [question.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/609842/baseband-uses-full-bandwidth-of-the-entire-link-or-portion-of-the-bandwidth)

We know that modern Ethernet is full-duplex. At the same time, we can send or receive the signal. Suppose I consider one LAN where multiple hosts are connected by different ports of switch.

[image]

Let's take Host A connected to switch port N via a baseband link. Consider if A starts sending its intended signal to switch port N for host B and C at the same time.

My question is: how does Host A use the entire bandwidth of that baseband link, despite it sending multiple signals (frames) for different intended hosts at the same time?

Comment: @All - The long, ongoing comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Also, the comments are starting to repeat the new question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/614919). (Note that comments should not ask new questions.) Therefore comments have been moved to chat and should be continued there (link below). --- Any further comments posted here may be deleted without notice. **Keep it in chat now, please!** Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135376/discussion-on-question-by-lionheart-how-ethernet-uses-full-bandwidth-of-the-link).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term ‘multiplexing’ means different things in different contexts.

Eg. WDM (Wavelength Division Multiplexing) is a method of using two (or more) different colored lasers to send the data on a common optic fiber. Magic optical techniques are used to combine and separate the different colors. In terms of data being sent down one laser color, it is serial (there are probably more advanced techniques used in the very fast telco stuff).

In the case of VDSL (Very high-speed Digital Subscriber Line), multiple bits are sent at the same time. Does this mean that packets for Google and Facebook are sent at the same time or that one packet is split into multiple channels? Either is possible, but the latter is more likely.

So we can talk of multiplexing sockets over ethernet and multiplexing bits over VDSL; two very different techniques with the same concept. So don’t conflate all uses of the term ‘multiplex’ to mean the same thing. And multiplexing does not imply many things at one time.

Think of transferring data packets like a courier system - eg. Fedex. You put your various bits in a box. Your box goes into a van with other boxes. The boxes go to sorting points to go onto different modes of transport. At the destination the boxes get sorted and your box gets delivered to the ultimate destination. The receiver opens the box and separates the various bits. That’s basically the internet.

Comment: "multiplexing bits over vdsl "---don't understand? What do u mean?

Comment: Vsdl uses OFDM encoding which creates a number of low bit rate channels that run in parallel to create an agile combined data channel. You’ll want a maths degree to understand how it works.

Comment: "multiplexing sockets over ethernet  "-- please elaborate little bit?

Comment: You can have multiple tcp socket connections active over the one ethernet connection i.e. multiplexed. But only one packet is sent/received at one time.

Comment: "multiplexing sockets over ethernet" ---- could we tell it is baseband channel and "multiplexing bits over VDSL"----could we tell it is broadband channel?

Comment: ‘Could we tell’? By what means? You’re using your browser - can you tell how the data is getting to you via the various paths it traverses? I can’t.

Comment: Ethernet is baseband channel which carried digital signal. But I read from Wikipedia article that TDM is used multiplexing of digital signal. My question is if physical layer not used multiplexing, so why TDM is used?

Comment: Where did you read this? I looked at the Wikipedia entry on Ethernet and saw no reference to TDM.

Comment: @Lionheart - Please stop adding a repeat of your [new question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/614919/why-is-time-division-multiplexing-tdm-used-in-the-physical-layer) in comments here as well. Such duplication is not welcome and wastes site members' time here, as they may repeat responses / advice / answers etc. already given on your new topic. Thanks.