# Why is time division multiplexing (TDM) used in the physical layer?

Tags: signal, multiplexer, tdma

We know that in the physical layer, we don't use any multiplexing, and Ethernet is a baseband channel which carries a digital signal, but I read in the Wikipedia article that TDM is used multiplexing of digital signals.

If the physical layer does not use multiplexing, why is TDM used?

I am computer science student, I don't understand in depth knowledge of signalling.  To understand  the computer network I have required some basic concepts of electrical engineering. Please don't use too much technical term.

Comment: Your question is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @KevinWhite I am asking if physical layer not using multiplexing, so why time division Multiplexing is used in physical layer?

Comment: TDM at the physical layer IS multiplexing.

Comment: @KevinWhite But physical layer in baseband channel don't use multiplexing.. So why we ise TDM for physical layer?

Comment: Why do you say that? That is incorrect.

Comment: @KevinWhite [See this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/612423/how-ethernet-uses-full-bandwidth-of-the-link-if-one-host-is-sending-more-than-on) , my previous question, from where I came to know that physical layer don't use multiplexing for baseband channel...

Comment: I highly suggest taking your questions to your professor. You seem to be missing some fundamental knowledge to really understand the concept of TDM and how it is applied in a TCP/IP or OSI network model. I’m worried that an explanation to any specific question you have may just confuse you more.

Comment: @Ryan I understand the TDM, but one thing tell why is it used for multiplexing in baseband signal at physical layer? We know that physical layer don't use multiplexing..

Comment: This question has nothing to do with electrical engineering, this is a network engineering question. You are speaking mainly about Ethernet PHY. Ethernet can only send one packet at a time and it can already sends packets from multiple programs in an interleaved fashion. It is designed to be packet switched network so it does not use TDM. Other networks that are not packet switched are circuit switched and will use TDM.

Comment: @Justme insert the comment in answer.

Comment: @Lionheart Why? This is a comment to your question, not a comment to any answer.

Comment: @Justme circuit switched network which use TDM , it analog signal or digital signal?

Comment: @Justme give one example TDM work with digital signal?

Comment: It's traditionally used in the telecoms industry to combine multiple slower connections into faster backbone links, e.g. 31 E0 channels of 64kbps into one E1 link at 2048kbps, four E1s into a single E2 at 8448kbps and so on.

Comment: @Finbarr these slower links carried digital signal and as well faster backbone link also digital signal?

Comment: All digital, can be on fiber rather than cable at the higher speeds.

Comment: @Finbarr that's why I am asking your above mentioned example, slower link which carries digital signal and faster backbone link carries analog?

Comment: @Finbarr please confirm me above confusion then my whole concepts will be clear.

Comment: Apart from the plain old telephone service (POTS), pretty much everything in the telecoms world is digital. And BT is trying hard to get rid of that in the UK too.

Comment: @Finbarr telephone line carries both analog and digital signal ?Analog signal which is converted from digital signal by modem (**for internet data**) carried by DSL line. And for **telephone data** which is analog and converted to digital for transmission through telephone line. Am I correct for both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-division_multiplexing):

> Time-division multiplexing (TDM) is a method of transmitting and receiving independent signals over a common signal path by means of synchronized switches at each end of the transmission line so that each signal appears on the line only a fraction of time in an alternating pattern.

Note this is completely different from TCP/IP which uses packets. Packets are not TDM.

So, you have a transmission channel, for example cable, fiber, radio waves, etc, and you want to transmit several data streams on this channel. This is especially applicable if the channel bandwidth is higher than what a stream needs, so you might as well use the full bandwidth, or you have a variable number of streams to transmit, but the number of wires is fixed, or just for cost, or convenience.

I'll use simple examples of TDM audio formats: I2S and TDM. That's what the DSP chip in your AV receiver uses to talk to the DACs to turn the digital samples into analog signals.

As the definition above says, TDM is synchronous, which means both ends use the same clock. It is either embedded in the signal or transmitted on its own wire. There is one clock cycle for every transmitted bit, so both ends of the channel know where the bits are.

The next important thing about TDM is that both ends agree beforehand on what the data format is. This is either done through software configuration or setting levels on configuration pins. So, both ends agree to slice the channel into time intervals, measured in clock cycles, which are clearly known and labeled, for example "left" and "right" in the case of audio. For multichannel, you could have channel1 to channel8.

Then, both ends also agree about how many bits will be transmitted in each interval, in what order the bits will be transmitted, what they represent, etc. For example, a channel can be a 32-bit integer value, with the bits sent MSB-first.

This establishes a clear transmission schedule, and both ends know what each bit is and where it should go once it is received. This schedule is called a frame, which is composed of slots (for example one slot per channel) with each slot containing a fixed number of bits.

This means TDM also requires a means to encode when the frame starts, so the receiver can align with the sender. In the audio formats I use as an example, this is a separate signal, which is called "Left/Right" or "Frame clock". It could also be embedded in the signal.

One advantage of TDM is its simplicity. The disadvantage is lack of flexibility: since the frame schedule is fixed, if one stream has nothing to transmit, its slot is allocated anyway, so it can't be reused for other streams. Thus it is well suited to constant data rate streams, like audio, HDMI video, or phone calls, but absolutely not for internet.

Now, what I want to emphasize is that TDM is a "by contract" format, where both ends agree about everything before beginning the transmission. IP networking is the complete opposite: while the transmission media is shared, packets arrive... when they arrive. While the TDM receiver always knows what it is going to receive next, because the schedule is fixed, the IP receiver does not. Packets just come on the wire.

With IP, many users can send packets on the same media, because the packets contain headers will all the information about sender, receiver, etc. So when a router receives a packet, it can check the headers to know what to do with it.

I think your confusion comes from the fact both TDM and IP (or more accurately, Ethernet physical layer) use time-sharing, that is using the media for different data streams. But the way they work is completely different.

TDM is basically a train. Each frame is a train, each slot is a wagon, it's on a schedule, with only one route, and that's it.

IP is more like postal service, where you write the address on the envelope and drop it in the mailbox.

Comment: @Lionheart I would encourage you to reflect on the tone of your comments, I appreciate you may not be using your native language. Others have identified you may not currently have the knowledge base to fully understand what you are asking but some have tried to construct fairly comprehensive answers none the less. In response to this a lot of your comments are straight demands for them to further explain concepts, often very broad, quite basic or based on misconceptions. I think this is one where you need to take it back to your professor.

Comment: @bobflux generally we know that telephone line uses analog signal, during phone call data is travelling through digital signal that uses TDM. My question is telephone line could be both digital or analog signal?

Comment: Wired telephone is usually analog from the handset to the central, then all digital. There are plenty of ways to cram as many phone calls as possible into cables or fibers, TDM is one, there was frequency division multiplexing in the time of coax, also ATM, sometimes they run it over IP... As for wireless: Analog cellphones are extinct, now cellphones are digital from the handset.

Comment: @bobflux "Wired telephone is usually analog from the handset to the central, then all digital"--- this statement not understanding. You mean from my home land phone line carried analog signal to central? What you mean by "central"? "then all digital"--- where to where is digital?but I know telephone tower carries analog signal for long distance upto receiver?

Comment: Only the local loop is analog, it's only a few miles. It is converted to digital in the exchange, which is a building somewhere in your neighborhood where the telecom companies house all the hardware for this, also hardware for DSL, fiber, etc.

Comment: @bobflux telephone line carries both analog and digital signal? Analog signal which is converted from digital signal by modem (**for internet data**)  carried by DSL line. And for **telephone data** which is analog and converted to digital for transmission through telephone line. Am I correct for both cases?

Comment: Yes, the voice calls are carried as analog to the exchange. In the old days of 56k modems, these used the same frequency range as voice, and it was treated as voice by the telecom infrastructure, so it required no special equipment in the exchange. DSL uses much higher frequencies on the same wire for higher bandwidth, and it requires special DSL equipment in the exchange .

Comment: "the voice calls are carried as analog to the exchange "---- you mean exchange is central where TDM is used for multiplexing of different user and where telephone line carried digital signal? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct

Comment: @bobflux My final confusion check me correct or not:: In packet switched network digital signal go through number of routers, then use modem at a time which converts digital to analog, this analog signal go through with telephone DSL line? Am I correct?

Comment: You could say a modem signal is digital, because it's just encoded data

Comment: @bobflux modem converts digital signal to analog signal, then  we could say digital signal travel as analog signal through telephone line?

Comment: The modem just applies a special encoding to the signal, but it is still a digital signal, it is not analog voice for example. In fact, all digital signals are always transmitted as analog, for example as voltage.

Comment: @bobflux I don't understand the difference between """transmitted as analog signal""" and """analog signal ""?

Comment: It's simple. The difference is the meaning we give to it. Consider the numbers "0" and "1" written on a page. If you look at the density of ink, it's analog. But if you decide the shape "0" means the number "0", and you decide that these are bits, then it's also digital. Likewise, you can decide voltage on a wire means 0 below 1.5V, and 1 above 3.6V. The voltage is analog, but it represents a digital value.  If you feed this signal into a logic gate, it will interpret it as bits. If you feed it into an opamp, it'll interpret it as voltage.

Comment: Basically, a "digital signal" on a wire is always an analog signal, like voltage, because wires don't carry bits. But both ends of the transmission agree that this voltage represents a finite number of information states, for example bits. So the output of a 56k modem, for example, is an analog signal, a waveform, that encodes bits. You could speak "zero, one, zero", and your voice would be an analog signal carrying bits too.

Comment: @bobflux "Basically, a "digital signal" on a wire is always an analog signal "----- you mean after modem on then telephone line?

Answer (score 1):

I’m going to attempt to answer the question as, “how is multiplexing used in a TCP/IP network?” With an emphasis on why it is *not* used at the physical layer.

We need to start with a basic description of the TCP/IP network structure which is compared with the OSI network structure in this image:

[image]

Source: https://onlinesmarttrainer.blogspot.com/2019/08/comparison-of-osi-reference-model-and.html?m=1

Now let’s talk about how multiplexing is used with an example. Let’s say you’re studying late one night and you want to go onto EE.SE to ask a question. You get on your computer and go to the EE.SE website in your web browser. Your computer uses an application called HTTPS to send a message to EE.SE asking it to send over the home page information so it can be displayed on your browser. This message is constructed by the HTTPS application (application layer) and then sent down to the “Transport layer.”

If multiple applications on your device want to send data over the network, the transport layer has to multiplex those messages. One method used for multiplexing is TDM, where each application is given a time window to send its data. That method in this context is called TDMoIP, but most internet applications use a different method called TCP. TCP assigns sockets to each application and organizes messages from these applications into packets before sending them over the the network layer.

The network layer adds a header to the TCP packets with source and destination IP addresses, and then sends those packets on to the network interface layer.

The network interface layer has two jobs. It functions as the data link layer and the physical layers in the OSI network model. One of the main jobs of the data link layer is *multiple access control* (MAC). This is essentially how multiple users can send data over a single channel without interference (I.e. “contention”).

For example, if I’m trying to use the internet to get onto EE.SE while my sister is also using the internet to get onto Facebook and we are sharing the same router, the router has to figure out how to send and receive data for both of us on the same coax or fiber optic cable without our packets interfering with each other. This process is called multiple access control because it controls the access of multiple users. It is similar to multiplexing but it is not multiplexing, and it is done on the data link layer, not the physical layer.

Different methods for multiple access control that you can research are time division multiple access (TDMA), code division multiple access (CDMA), orthogonal frequency division multiple access (OFDMA), ALOHA, and statistical multiple access methods.

Once the data link layer has added the MAC header, as the bits are being sent out of the processor in your computer, they go through another computer chip (IC) called an “Ethernet PHY.” This chip takes the signals from your CPU and conditions them in a specific way to meet the Ethernet protocol before sending it through your Ethernet cable over to its destination at the EE.SE server. The physical layer is only concerned about getting the physical signal through the channel. It doesn’t do any sort of multiplexing or multiple access.

After your message gets to the EE.SE servers, it goes back up through all the layers and is processed by the site’s HTTPS application. And just like that you ask your question and hopefully get a useful answer (although the entire process takes several interactions between your computer and the EE.SE server).

Disclaimer: this is a bit of an oversimplification of the process used to send and receive data on a TCP/IP (packet switched) network, but hopefully it helps illustrate the concept of multiplexing well enough to answer the question.

Comment: one thing don't understand how I and my sister send data at same time with same coax, I connected with router with one cable, how one cable is shareable?

Comment: We’re going around in circles now. ‘Same time’ to what you perceive is not quite the same as what is really happening. Didn’t we estsblish in your other question that one data packet is sent at a time? The magic is that the data packets are sent fast enough that you perceive it as the ‘same time’.

Comment: What happens on the coaxial cable between your coax cable modem and your internet service provider has nothing to do with this any more, as that is not Ethernet.

Comment: @Justme telephone line carries both analog and digital signal ?Analog signal which is converted from digital signal by modem (**for internet data**) carried by DSL line. And for **telephone data** which is analog and converted to digital for transmission through telephone line. Am I correct for both cases?